# C++ code does not work correctly?

Tags: c++

For the following code I have a problem. I want it to print out the print statement which matches the if statement, but instead, it prints ALL of the statements for each if statement. How do I rectify this? I'm a beginner you see, so sorry for the silly question..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    cout << "Enter your first number" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    cout << "Enter your third number" << endl;
    cin >> z;

    ////////////Equilateral Triangle. All sides are the same/////////////
    if ((x == y) && (y == z)) {
        cout << "This is an Equilateral triangle" << endl;
    }

    ////////////Isoceles Triangle. Two sides are the same/////////////
    if ((x == y) or (y == z) or (z == x)) {
        cout << "This is an Isosceles triangle" << endl;
    }

    ////////////Scalene Triangle. All sides are different/////////////
    if ((x > y + z)or (y > x + z) or (z > x +y)) {
        cout << "Opps! That didn't work! " << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "This is a scalene triangle" << endl;
    }

    return 0; // exit program
}
```

Comment: Huh, how exactly can `(x > y + y) **or** (y > x + z)` work?

Comment: You know you can use `!=` for "not equal", right?

Comment: `else`.................

Comment: _'How do I rectify this?'_ SO isn't a debug and fix my code service ...

Comment: @Xarn see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/or it is an alternative to || and comes from a time when not all computers had a | character

Comment: Okay, my bad. (I knew about digraphs but didn't about those.)

Comment: the code is incomplete, please edit.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if ( x != y and y !=z and z !=x) {
        cout << "This is a scalene triangle" << endl;
    }
```

You could also assume that if it isn't Equilateral or Isosceles than it is Scalene

```
////////////Equilateral Triangle. All sides are the same/////////////
if ((x == y) && (y == z)) {
        cout << "This is an Equilateral triangle" << endl;

}

////////////Isoceles Triangle. Two sides are the same/////////////
else if ((x == y) or (y == z) or (z == x)) {
        cout << "This is an Isosceles triangle" << endl;
}

////////////Scalene Triangle. All sides are different/////////////
else {
        cout << "This is a scalene triangle" << endl;
    }
```